# netsh set ip address errors

Tags: windows-xp, netsh

I want to set the IP address, subnet and gateway using netsh. I have Windows XP on my computer. 
When I type the command:

```
set address "Local Area Connection" static ipAdd sub gateway
```

I get this error:

> Environment variable address "Local Area Connection" static ipAdd sub gateway not defined

When I type:

```
netsh interface ip  set address "Local Area Connection" static ipAdd sub gateway
```

I get a different error:

```
the following command was not found.
```

The DNS and WINS details were successfully set, and I can set the IP settings by typing them by in the Internet Protocol Panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right syntax for the setting ip address command via netsh is  :

```
netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.20 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1 1
```

and setting the dns with the next line :

```
netsh interface ip set dns "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.200 primary
```

add secondary dns :

```
netsh interface ip add dns "Local Area Connection" 192.168.0.201 index=2
```

here's [a link](http://lantoolbox.com/articles/netsh-tips-and-tricks-for-network-administrator/)!